# Error getting an access token for c# webforms using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, oauth-2.0

I've searched through atleast 100 hundred access token issues but have not found an solution for my issue.  I am using the facebook sdk to auth but when I try to simple .Get on "me" it errors out with this error: "(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."   I am using .NET 3.5 framework so I can not use 'dynamic'.  When I substitute a valid id where "me" it works and shows the name.  When I try to post to feed I get the "(OAuthException) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action."
Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var requestString = "client_id=[appid]&client_secret=[secret]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access";

        byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
        webRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

        var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString))
        {
            var accessToken = responseString.Replace("access_token=", "");
            var fb = new FacebookWebClient(accessToken.ToString());
            var me = fb.Get<FBUser>("100000219214008");
            string firstName = me.name;
            var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            postparameters["message"] = "Hello world!";
            postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
            postparameters["link"] = "http://thisisalink.com";
            postparameters["description"] = "This is a description";
            var result = fb.Post("/100000219214008/feed", postparameters); 
            Response.Write (firstName.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: In regards to facebook WEBFORM problems, it seems that not many people are using it in this fashion.  There is little to none in ways of documentation for this method. All samples focus on Winforms or MVC.  MVC is so bloated I don't understand why anyone would want to use it unless they love the convoluted way that MVC works. An ad agency that I worked for spent $750k on a project and spent over 6 months with a team of 10 developers [outsourced] and the project was like 80megs! I re-wrote the site using a simple webform and template in 30minutes - 350kilobytes total project.

Comment: Anyways.. It just seems like there needs to be support from the facebook sdk c# regarding web forms since I can't imagine anyone using MVC for one page. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for days with the Facebook C# SDK, I chose to go with the Facebook Javascript SDK. This SDK has wide support, examples and documentation although it is client-side. It just works.